# Як правильно писати "декоративно листяні рослини"?

Tags: правопис, складні-прикметники, разом-дефіс-окремо

*Google* та *Microsoft Office Word* видають різні варіанти написання слів:

1. **разом**
   (декоративнолистяні та красивоквітучі кімнатні рослини),
2. **окремо** (декоративно листяні та красиво квітучі рослини),
3. **через дефіс** (декоративно-листяні та кравиво-квітучі рослини).

В словниках не знайшла.

Як правильно писати?

Comment: Фактичний узус — дефісне написання: Google Книги ([18](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22декоративно-листяна%22+OR+%22декоративно-листяне%22+OR+%22декоративно-листяні%22) — [2](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22декоративнолистяний%22+OR+%22декоративнолистяна%22+OR+%22декоративнолистяне%22)), Google Scholar ([70](//scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22декоративно-листяна%22+OR+%22декоративно-листяне%22+OR+%22декоративно-листяні%22) — [16](//scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22декоративнолистяний%22+OR+%22декоративнолистяна%22+OR+%22декоративнолистяне%22+OR+%22декоративнолистяні%22)).

Comment: «Декоративно(-)листяний» можна вважати уточненням до просто «листяний», а «красиво(-)квітучий» — до просто «квітучий», а це теоретично можна «підігнати» під [§ 29.2д «Правопису»](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par29p2d): «Через дефіс пишуться <…> складні прикметники, утворені з двох або кількох основ, які означають якість із додатковим відтінком <…>: <…>, *молочно-білий*, <…>, *темно-зелений* <…>».

Comment: Тож доки не з'явиться інших даних я би радив писати через дефіс. Але: це зовсім не відповідь, я можу дуже помилятися, я не мовознавець.

Comment: @Sasha дякую. Я думаю, що треба писати через дефіс, але ніякого підтвердження цьому не знайшла.

Comment: Хм, перепрошую, я дивився частоту траплянь лише для «декоративно(-)листяний». А для «красиво(-)квітучий» виявилося навпаки — частіше пишуть разом.

Comment: Тобто практика за «декоративно-листяні» (через дефіс) та «красивоквітучі» (разом).

Comment: І мабуть, у коментарі про «§ 29.2д» я написав маячню: якщо вважати перше слово уточненням, то якраз мало би писатися разом за [§ 29.1ґ](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par29p1g), а не через дефіс.

Comment: Мабуть, я б писав так, як пишуть найчастіше: «**декоративно-листяні**» (через дефіс) та «**красивоквітучі**» (разом).

Comment: @Sasha але там 4 проти 2, а не 18 проти 2.

Comment: @P.Vovk, так, Ви праві. (Мені, якщо чесно, спочатку взагалі  здалося, що треба писати декоративно(-)листяні разом, бо від «декоративний лист», а це § 29.1б, але потім засумнівався. Фактично, якщо «декоративний» — це вточнення, то разом за § 29.1ґ, а якщо це паралельні характеристики, то, можливо, через дефіс. А ще є декоративно(-)хвойні і красиво(-)плідні — і врешті-решт я загубився. Може, у Вас є ідеї?)

Comment: @Sasha, до речі, а слово «**напів-відповіді** у коментарях» пишеться разом, окремо чи через дефіс? :-)

Comment: @bytebuster, разом. Через дефіс лише для власних назв, а-ля пів-Європи. (Окремо наразі лише для зворотів на зразок «пів на третю», хоча в проекті-1999 була, по-моєму, непогана провозиція писати всі «пів» (але не «напів») окремо, зробивши «пів» повноцінним числівником, але її не прийняли.)

Answer (score 1):

У статті на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) бачимо речення: "Належать до листяно-декоративних кімнатних рослин". Також про те, що варто писати "декоративно-листяні рослини" чи "листяно-декоративні", можна знайти на багатьох сайтах присвячених садівництву, наприклад в онлайн [енциклопедії кімнатних рослин](http://rasteniya.in.ua/kimnatni-kviti/dekorativno-listyani-kimnatni-roslini/). Крім того, у книзі "Інтродукція та акліматизація рослин на Україні" бачимо речення: "При науково-дослідній роботі, у закритому грунті поповнюється асортимент промислового квітництва красивоквітучими (у горщиках та зрізі) та декоративно-листяними рослинами".